# Runtime error using range with variable name in it

Tags: excel, vba, split

I am getting a runtime error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed when running my code.  It should be splitting the data in the source column into a destination specified by the first blank column in the array.  Because the source data is erratically formatted it needs to look for tabs or line breaks as the delimiter.  I am using variable names for the source and blank columns as they are not at a fixed position in the array.

```
Dim CurrentCol As Integer
Dim FirstCol As Integer
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim ColName As String
Dim BlankCol As Integer
Dim Source As Range
Dim SourceCol As String
Dim SourceAdd As String
Dim FirstColName As String
        
            
BlankCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
FirstCol = BlankCol + 1
Cells(1, FirstCol).Value = "FirstCol"
FirstColName = Cells(1, FirstCol).Value

Cells(1, BlankCol).Value = "Unique Classes"
Set Source = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("International", LookIn:=xlValues)
SourceCol = Source.Column
SourceAdd = Source.Address

Range(SourceAdd).EntireColumn.TextToColumns _
    Destination:=Range("PatBase[[#Headers], [" & FirstColName & "]]"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    Tab:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:="" & Chr(10) & "",_
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
    1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), _
    Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Once the data is in the columns I then have more code which truncates it to 4 characters with the range in the same format, but this is working fine:

```
CurrentCol = FirstCol

For i = FirstCol To LastCol
Columns(CurrentCol).Select
ColName = Cells(1, CurrentCol).Value
If ColName = "" Then
    Exit For
End If

Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("PatBase[[#Headers], [" & ColName & "]]"), _
    DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(4, 9)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
CurrentCol = CurrentCol + 1
Next i
```

I suspect I am missing something obvious but I'm not a skilled macro writer so am at a loss.  Can anyone help?

Comment: It would help if you indicated where the error occurs.

Comment: Most likely your new column is not part of your `PatBase` table, since you left a blank cell between the last header cell and the `FirstCol` header.

Comment: Are "Selection" and PatBase on the same sheet? If not, this could be the problem.

Comment: Error is on the Range(SourceAdd).EntireColumn.TextToColumns row.

Comment: @Rory: that is very plausible as the junk text I've put into the top cell in the column is not formatted as the rest of the table.  How do I address that?

Comment: Don't leave a blank cell in between that cell and the rest of the table, then your table should typically auto-expand. You could also explicitly resize it first.

Comment: Magical, thank you